# Unusual behavior from excel formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I managed to get the following to work:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(CUSIP2,SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(CUSIP2,O2))*ROW($2:$5158))),"")
```

What this does is it checks the contents of a cell against a list, and if a word on the list appears anywhere in the cell, it gives me what word it is. Great! Ideally, it'd also give me a blank if there's no matches in the cell. This is where I'm running into trouble.

When there is a match, it works perfectly. Without a match, it'll throw a random word instead of giving a blank. For example, it's giving me SWPC12374
in the cell "outgoing wire for CLIENT at BANK - offsetting entry not posted to SYSTEM"

Now, the mystery deepens. The wrong words thrown are always different. The wrong words thrown correspond directly to where in the list they are. For example, [WORD 1] is thrown in the first cell where I have the equation, and it's supposed to be blank. [WORD 2] is thrown in the second cell where I have the equation, and it's also supposed to be blank. Etc. [WORD 1] and [WORD 2] are the first two entries in the list CUSIP2, and the other incorrect entries are the corresponding entries on the CUSIP2 list.

Alternatively, they're also on the same row. So the first equation occurs on the second row, and the first term in the list occurs on the second row.

Now, when I dig into it with the formula solver, it very neatly ends with INDEX(CUSIP2,0) - then throws the wrong word in, iferror doesn't catch it, and it happily posts the wrong word.

I'm going nuts trying to trace this error, and I can't fathom why excel is doing this. Please help. My google-fu has failed me (if I even knew the proper terms to search for this)

Comment: Can you post some sample data, with some that work, and some that throws this error? (If the data is sensitive, please obfuscate it so it doesn't reveal anything confidential)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel INDEX doesn't like 0 as an index number. Here is an example matching your descrption:

```
Name 'Cups2'    INDEX(cups2,0)  INDEX(cups2,1)
hi              hi              hi
go              go              hi
now             now             hi
three           three           hi
five            five            hi
gal             gal             hi
```

Can you edit your data so that the first entry in the CUSPID2 range is ""? Then you could modify the formula to return that 1st entry when the index is 0:

```
=INDEX(CUSIP2,MAX(1,SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(CUSIP2,O2))*ROW($2:$5158))))
```

Comment: I like it! I'm making one modification to it, where I'm putting a long string into the index (This was a triumph, I'm making a note here, huge success) to avoid potentially ever triggering a match. Thank you!